# making a CLI entry point for a library

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I have written a library with the following structure:

```
libProject/
  setup.py
  libname/
     __init__.py
     script1.py
     script2.py
     ...
```

I use it primarily by importing it

```
from libname.script1 import Fun1
...
```

I would now like to make a command line interface to it, but I'm confused where do I put my `argpase` code within this project so that I can use

```
$ python libname <somecommand>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Would still keep it open for better answers.

- In the `libname` directory, touch a new file called `__main__.py`
- `libname.__main__` will be executed when `libname` directory is called as script.

Now put your command line code inside this file

```
#__main__.py

import sys
from .script1 import Fun1
print Fun1(sys.arg[-1])
```